# How to fix "Invalid Element 'license' in element 'metadata' on nuget pack

Tags: nuget

I am calling Nuget Pack on a nuget file that contains a "license" tag

```
license type="expression">MIT</license>
```

nuget pack fails as a result.

I have tried downloading the latest nuget.exe and placing it into the folder, and then using "cd" to change directory and call again. Still fails.

The exact error message is

```
The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'license' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'references, frameworkAssemblies, releaseNotes, iconUrl, summary, language, copyright, developmentDependency, serviceable, description, dependencies, repository, packageTypes, contentFiles, projectUrl, licenseUrl, tags' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. This validation error occurred in a 'license' element.
```

Comment: If you run nuget.exe without any parameters, it will print out help including the version number. Use it to ensure you're using the version you expect. From memory, license expressions were added about 4.8 or 4.9. The error you copied suggests you may be using an older version, despite attempts to download the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the zivkan's answer, I solved the problem.  As he said, I was running an older version of nuget.  Updating from nuget rather than downloading the binary worked.  To update, run

```
nuget update -self
```

Note that you may need to be running as administrator.

Comment: Note that the command from CLI is `nuget update -self` (single dash)